# Application Crash after adding subreport in crystal

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

devenv.exe error in ntdll.dll....
Don't know what happened. After adding subreport when i change format it doesn't even save...
When start debugging my visual studio stop responding..
This is the screenshot..
Any help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I don't see any screenshot.Please edit your question and add it

Comment: Is it still invisible??

Comment: is it visible now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also happened with me i searched for it and finally this solution worked for  me

In the Crystal report there is one option in the  preview 
if the checkbox "Save data in the report" is checked **unckeck** this checkbox. this was creating problem in saving my sub-report

See if this works for you..